# How to pass multiple parameters in @PUT method?

Tags: apache, rest, jaxb, cxf, jax-rs

I have a requirement to implement a method like this in Apache CXF JAX-RS(in a concurrent scenario)

```
@PUT
@Path("/customers/123")
public void updateConcurrentCustomer(Customer existingCustomer,Customer updatedCustomer,boolean forceUpdate){
......
}
```

In request body, i need to call this method something like this (no root element).

```
<Customer>
.....existing data....
</Customer>
<Customer>
......updated data....
</Customer>
<boolean>true</boolean>
```

How this data binding can be achieved?

I tried creating a composite wrapper Resource class like this

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CustomCustomer implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private Customer  existingCustomer;
    private Customer  updatedCustomer;
    private boolean forceUpdate;
    .....
    .....

}
```

It works well. But i dont want to create this wrapper class.

### My concurrency scenario:

1. customer123 object is in state A.
2. user1 changes customer123 to state B.
3. user2 changes customer123 to state C.
4. user3 changes customer123 to state D. (all at same time)

only high priority user sets forceUpdate flag and finally that update will be overwritten than others.

existingCustomer - will be used to detect conflict changes. It will be in state A

Comment: Your body does not contain one resource representation. What do they have in common?

Comment: Yes you are right. request body cantains different representation of same resource.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6)

> The PUT method requests that the enclosed entity be stored under the
>   supplied Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to an already existing
>   resource, the enclosed entity SHOULD be considered as a modified
>   version of the one residing on the origin server.

So first of all your customer needs a unique identifier like `/customers/{id}`. Otherwise the server can't know where the resource should be stored.

Then you don't need to pass the existingCustomer. Either there is none (new resource) or the server already knows him (because you addressed him with a unique URL).

The forceUpdate is also not senseful here. A PUT should modify if the resource already exists so forceUpdate is true be definition.

Sometimes you can't use the clear semantics of a PUT. For instance if the client does not know the id and you don't want that the client chooses one (he can't guarantee uniqueness). Then you can use a POST and the server will return the Location where he stored the Resource.

Also if you want to update only in special cases maybe depending on some other parameters a POST is the appropriate Method.

Comment: yes i agree. Please see my edited question for the issue i am facing.

Comment: I don't see a concurrency-problem here. As far as I understood there a users which can create and update and others which can only create. So I'd try to identify the user and tell him that the server did not PUT because the resource exists and the user has insufficient privileges for an update (maybe with error-code 409). So again: No need to pass the old resource. In general for concurreny-problems: A RESTful API should be stateless which simply means "last one wins".